# FragmentTabHost + Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragment-tab-host

Now, i had to implement the design exactly like android music app, also not use ActionBarSherlock, (i think official app also would be not using it)

neways by that design, i mean, to have a tab bar inside one of the fragments of a navigation drawer.

The way i thought and was able too also was, that implement normal navigation drawer with fragments, then use FragmentTabHost in one fragments to implement tab bar inside it.
The problem is i cant see the tab bar, but only the 1st tab opened by default.

while implemeting navigation drawer i also added support library 7 to get supoort actionbar(),  my best guess is that the tabbar is hidden behind the supportactionbar i get from support library,
my minimum SDK is 2.3.3. thats why i am going to that much trouble, any help on how to place the tab bar below the action bar.

also now after doing this my drawer is not working anymore, i just keep clicking on it, and its not opening up, any idea why ??
please ask if you require any clarification. !